# Linestring to CartoDB api

Tags: carto, api, linestring

I want to add a linestring to a CartoDB API web app for one time use, I have SQL statement being ran at the same time and just want the linestring in the SQL statement to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work

```
SELECT ST_Transform(
        ST_SetSRID( 
         ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{ "type": "LineString","coordinates": [ [27.456667,5.065], [30.456667,-1.088] ] }')
        ,4326)
       ,3857) AS the_geom_webmercator
```